# LoRa Ra-02 Module begin and beginPacket not working in Arduino Nano

Tags: arduino-ide, arduino-nano, wireless, lora, arduino-esplora

Here there, recently I am testing **Lora Ra-02 module** I saw many videos and it is easy to set up, according to this schematic:

> LoRa SX1278 Module-----Arduino Nano Board
>
> 3.3V-------
>
> Gnd---------Gnd
>
> En/Nss------D10
>
> G0/DIO0------D2
>
> SCK---------D13
>
> MISO----------D12
>
> MOSI----------D11
>
> RST-------------D9

I am using a very common library called [sandeepmistry](https://github.com/sandeepmistry/arduino-LoRa). and I tried this code:

```c
#include <SPI.h>
#include <LoRa.h>

int counter = 1;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial);
  Serial.println("LoRa Sender");
  if (!LoRa.begin(433E6)) {
    Serial.println("Starting LoRa failed!");
    while (1);
  }
}

void loop() {
  Serial.print("Sending packet: ");
  Serial.println(counter);
  // send packet
  LoRa.beginPacket();
  LoRa.print("hello ");
  LoRa.print(counter);
  LoRa.endPacket();
  counter++;
  delay(500);
}
```

When I run it, it just sticks in this line {Serial.println("**Starting LoRa failed!**");}

Then I updated the code and tried to reduce the SPI Frequency because I am using **Arduino Nano**  now the code is this:

```c
#include <SPI.h>
#include <LoRa.h>

int counter = 1;
int frequency = 8E6; // Set the desired frequency here

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial);
  Serial.println("LoRa Sender");
  LoRa.setSPIFrequency(frequency); // Add the missing semicolon here
  if (!LoRa.begin(433E6)) {
    Serial.println("Starting LoRa failed!");
    while (1);
  }
}

void loop() {
  Serial.print("Sending packet: ");
  Serial.println(counter);
  // send packet
  LoRa.beginPacket();
  LoRa.print("hello ");
  LoRa.print(counter);
  LoRa.endPacket();
  counter++;
  delay(500);
}
```

This code passes the line **Starting LoRa failed!** but it again stuck in here

> LoRa Sender
> Sending packet: 1

So why won't it do `LoRa.beginPacket();` and loop the code? Why does it stop here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you set the pins properly? Try doing:

```c
  LoRa.setPins(csPin, resetPin, irqPin);// set CS, reset, IRQ pin
```

There is a problem with the way your SX1276 is connected to the board, which is why `.begin()` returns false.